# Button click wont trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, button, click

I'm having trouble triggering a function. I have the following code:

```
var dnfmomd;

dnfmomd = new function () {
//function content
}

$("#launch_button").on("click", dnfmomd.init);
```

Comment: Does dnfmomd have an init method? Does jQuery find the element? Errors in console? did you debug with console.log() ?

Comment: [You need to provide a clear problem statement](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)  "having trouble" is really vague. What happens? What errors are reported? What have you done to debug it? You also need to provide a [mcve], ideally using the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var dnfmomd = function () {
//function content
}

$("#launch_button").on("click", dnfmomd());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing it this way

```
 var dnfmomd = function() {
 //function content
}

$("#launch_button").on("click", function() {
  dnfmomd();
});
```